# Looking for a specific book series about kids playing a computer game and getting sucked in!

Tags: story-identification

I was about 12 when I read this book (so about 11 years ago). I remember the front cover quite vividly so let's start off with that!
The cover has a green circuit board (all of them in the series had a circuit board texture in a specific colour I think) with the title being one word in bold red letters.
At the top right of the cover was a Japanese looking robot looking character (manga style, I believe!)
Now the story. I don't remember a lot but I do remember a group of kids at school (possibly high school) playing a computer game! Now judging by the style of the front cover im betting it was from the early 2000s.
Any suggestions!? I'm sorry it's not a lot to go on!

Comment: Awesome details, and great job with the cover, in my own experience that greatly helps Identification!

Comment: Actual circuit boards, not hexagons like https://www.publishersweekly.com/images/data/ARTICLE_LISTICLE_ITEM/override_image/000/000/111-1.JPG?

Comment: Although probably not your story, your description reminded me of [Code Lyoko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Lyoko)

Comment: Yeah it was actually circuit board! And very slightly embossed

Comment: Code lyoko looks pretty cool!

Comment: Oh and sorry for all the grammar mistakes! Had to write this quickly on my phone!

Comment: Definately not what you're looking for but reminiscent of User Unfriendly by Vivian Vande Velde

Answer (score 1):

You may find it's called [*Cyber Chase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberchase), a cartoon series which was later turned into books. The main antagonist is named Hacker.

> Cyberchase is an American/Canadian animated educational children's television series on PBS Kids. The series focuses around three Earth kids, Jackie, Matt, and Inez, who are brought into Cyberspace, a digital universe, to protect it from the evil Hacker. Using math in application with problem-solving skills, environment and weather, they are able to prevent Hacker from causing any more harm. In Cyberspace, they meet Digit, a cybird that helps the kids on their mission

....

> When three average Earth kids, Jackie, Matt, and Inez accidentally allow the Hacker access to Motherboard, the supreme ruler of Cyberspace, she becomes severely weakened by a virus. The kids are brought into Cyberspace in an effort to protect the world from the Hacker and his clumsy assistants Buzz and Delete until a cure is found. They join forces with Digit, and later many more Cybercitizens that turn out to be great friends who are willing to fight for Motherboard.

Comment: Could you explain why you believe Cyber Chase matches the OP's description?

Comment: No circuitboard cover, but the timeframe, and the idea of three kids getting sucked in, are correct.